# trouble with intersections and rectangles in 2D java game

Tags: java, java-2d, rectangles

**My game runs off of a loop**. I am having trouble with creating the floor of my game, I currently have a gravity effect so `if(falling = true)` the player will move downwards. I have made rectangles in my character to detect the top `getTop()`, bottom `getBottom()`, right `getRight()` and left `getLeft()` intersections. the problem is I don't know how to create my floor using rectangles. I don't know how to create rectangles every 32 pixels that can be detected.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    Rectangle block = new Rectangle(blockX + 32 * i, blockY, 32, 32)
}
```

this successfully creates the rectangles and renders them properly. but when i test for intersection in my `tick()` method it only works for the last rectangle created. 
(example of my tick method)

```
if(getBottom().intersects(block)){
   falling = false;
   playerY = blockY+32;
}

if(!getTop().intersects(block)){
   falling = true;
}
```

is there anyway I can make multiple (possible hundreds) of rectangles that have the same properties but can all be detected for intersection.

Comment: Looks like you're only creating a single block for the floor

Comment: You need some sort of container for your blocks.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yeah I’m only making one! Don’t know how I can make multiple but find their intersections as one! Any suggestions?